# How do ablatively cooled rocket engines compare to regeneratively cooled ones, in terms of mass?

Tags: engines, nozzle, mass, cooling, expandable

Assuming equivalent thrust and single continuous burn duration, is there a figure that roughly tells the difference in mass between these two engines cooling methods? This question focuses on first stage liquid fueled engines optimized for sea level up to separation altitude operation, by the way welcome any figures for vacuum engines.

Comment: An ablative engine consumes the thrust chamber to affect cooling while keeping enough structural integrity to keep chamber integral under pressure. One could design an ablative with very little safety margin that would be lower weight than one designed with larger safety margins for the same thrust level and anticipated thrust duration.   Question needs to be reworded to make comparisons between regen and ablative chamber comparable.  Off hand I think increase plumbing of regen would weigh more than ablative.  I worked on Apollo main service module engine that had ablative thrust chamber.

Comment: @tckosvic Thanks for the input, not sure at the moment how to reword so that comparison becomes possible, nor if such a broad comparison makes sense at all regarding the amount of other differences arising from one or the other cooling method.

Comment: An additional comment is that ablative chambers change performance as throat area gets larger as throat erodes.  On a long burn can be very significant.  Throat inserts of materials such as graphite were used as an attempt to reduce this.